# How to sort listbox ItemSource without calling c'tor of all objects? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I have the following listbox

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Containers}" AllowDrop="True" Margin="0,0,5,0">
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Content.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ContainerViewModel}">
        <local:ContainerUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

ContainerUserControl is the user control that has an expander (with header and content).
The view model is ContainerViewModel

The item source for the binding is:

```
    private ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel> _containers;
    public ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel> Containers
    {
        get => _containers;
        set
        {
            _containers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when i assign new collection for Containers, the constructor of each element is being called:

```
public partial class ContainerUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ContainerUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.Print("in ContainerUserControl");
    }
}
```

and if i have thousands of items, it may take very long time.
now let's say i have 10k items and i want to sort this collection using this code:

```
Containers = new ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel>(Containers.OrderByDescending(i => i.Name));
```

i will see that the usercontrol constructor is being called 10k times.
After reading some posts, i decided to implement in-place sorting by using "Move" method, but unfortunately, even if i do:

```
_containers.Move(0, 1);
```

i see that i go through userControl c'tor. and if i have thousands of move operations it's like using the orderby method and assign the sorted list.
moreover, i tried to create a new sorted collection and just switch between itemsSource, and it didn't help, still entered c'tor 10k times.

```
public ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel> SortedContainers { get; set; } // already sorted
public ListBox ContainerListBox { get; set; } // the listbox from xaml

ContainerListBox.ItemsSource = null;
ContainerListBox.ItemsSource = SortedContainers;
```

No matter what i tried, i could not avoid from the c'tor to be called thousands of time and make terrible performance issues.
How can i avoid the c'tor calling? why this c'tor is being called no matter what?

Any help will be appreciated :)

EDIT:
i made some time measurements for 500 objects:
i see that each c'tor usually takes 1-2 ms but sometimes more than 20ms.
moreover, the total time for constructing the 500 objects collection is greater than sum all c'tor time together.
here are the start and the end of my measurements:
\nstart:
[image]
end:
[image]

you can see that the sum of all c'tor times is 1169ms but the total time is 18:52:25.835 - 18:52:29.153 which is 3.318 SECONDS.(usually it takes about 4 seconds for 500 objects so thing about 10k and even more)
why is that?

EDIT2:
I just noticed that not all my listbox code was pasted in the code section, the last part was missing...
the rest is:

```
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" AllowDrop="True"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Focusable="False">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

after long long investigation, i tried to make a small demo and started step by step building the control to see where the virtualization is messed.
long story short - after lots of playing around with the controls, i found out that the CanContentScroll="False" is block the virtualization. so the solution is to set it to true and add to listbox VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel" to achieve the same behavior and keep the virtualization.

thanks to @BionicCode for the instructions that helped me find the problem and the solution.

Comment: maybe keeping the ObservableCollection is an option? Maybe you can use Clear() and AddRange() instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @jeb same outcome

Comment: InitializeComponent() of the ContainerUserControl is taking long ? Maybe you could optimize whats in there for performance.

Comment: Why don't you use `ListCollectionView` with setting `IsLiveSorting` true? Do you need to change sorting property or direction each time?

Comment: @jeb something in creating the new collection and initialize all userControls take long time.

Comment: @emoacht the sort is by button click in the UI

Comment: How many elements are visible in the view port? It should only create a `UserControl` for those items and maybe a few more if UI virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @mm8 12 elements. but all the collection is being initialized no matter what i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListBox` uses UI virtualization. It does not load all items. Only those that are within the virtualization viewport. Because virtualization is enabled by default the overriding of the `ListBox.ItemPanel` is redundant.
Same applies to the DataCOntext binding inside the `DataTemplate`: the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` (or of the parent element in general) is implicitly inherited. No need to set it explicitly.

In your case all items are loaded because your `ListBox` has no height constraint. It will automatically stretch to make all items fit. To enable UI virtualization assign the `ListBox` a `Height` so that the `ScrollViewer` can work. The `ScrollViewer` is essential for UI virtualization.
The height can be set explicitly, for example by setting the `ListBox.Height` property or implicitly, for example by adding the `ListBox` to a `Grid` where the row height is set to anything but `Auto`.

In addition you should not replace the source collection. It's not efficient at all. This seriously compromises performance. Filtering, sorting and grouping is done by modifying the `CollectionView` that is bound to the `ItemsControl`. In WPF the binding engine will automatically use the default `ColectionView` to display the items. This allows you to modify the displayed items without modifying the original underlying collection. For example, sorting a `CollectionView` will not sort the underlying collection.

You use the static `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` method to obtain the default `CollectionView`:

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Containers}"
         VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
         Height="300">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="ContainerViewModel">
      <ContainerUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```cs
private ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel> _containers;
public ObservableCollection<ContainerViewModel> Containers
{
  get => _containers;
  set
  {
    _containers = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}

private void SortContainersByName()
{
  var sortDescription = new SortDescription(nameof(ContainerViewModel.Name), ListSortDirection.Ascending);
  ICollectionView containersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Containers);

  // Apply sorting criteria
  containersView.SortDescriptions.Add(sortDescription);
}

private void ClearSortContainersByName()
{
  SortDescription sortDescriptionToRemove = this.DataGridItemsView.SortDescriptions
    .FirstOrDefault(sortDescription => sortDescription.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(ContainerViewModel.Name), StringComparison.Ordinal));
  ICollectionView containersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Containers);

  // Clear sorting criteria
  containersView.SortDescriptions.Remove(sortDescriptionToRemove);
}
```

Comment: tried to set height and it didnt help. also tried your sort and entered c;tor as the collection length

Comment: Height must be set on the ListBox. You should use a visual tree inspector like integrated into Visual Studio or Snoop. It allows you to inspect the visual tree during runtime. When expand the ListBox to dig dow to the ItemsPanel you should see that it contains all items ==> no virtualization. If you only se like 20 items virtualization is working. It would be helpful if you could  check this to verify that your virtualization is disabled. *"also tried your sort and entered c;tor as the collection length"* - what do you mean, isn't it working?

Comment: isn't working in terms of performance improvements. still initialize all collection (500 objects).
about live visual tree i see there all the objects 500 with number of 22000 inner components of this collection (43 each container). see my edit in post please

Comment: You say you have a collection of 500 items. And all 500 item containers are created immediately. If this is the case than you have UI virtualization disabled. Please create a new test project that only contains the ListBox with a Height of 200 to prove that your code generally is working. You should see that only a very small number of item containers is generated.

Comment: From here you should do two things: you can then extend this demo test code to reconstruct the actual UI context/layout of your application to find where you disable it. And second, edit your question to post the context of the ListBox. It's important to show how it is embedded in the layout.

Comment: The point is, your current code does not reproduce your reported issue. It would be nice if you could create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You should start with plain ListBox where UI virtualization is working as expected. This way we have something relevant to review. Finding a fix should be very straight forward then. Chances are high that you find the fix yourself why trying to make the ListBox fail (according to your real code).

Comment: as you suggested, started step by step and made some minimal version of my app to reproduce the problem. finally i got it. problem was found and the solution was much easier than i thought . See my EDIT2 section. thanks alot! will accept your answer

Comment: This are good news. Then my assumption that you had turned off UI virtualization was correct. Good job that you were able to track it down. Good luck with your project.